# GIT: more than one developer working on the same feature

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-workflow

I have a question regarding on what's the best workflow for the following scenario.

Currently there are 2 branches:

- master
- development

master only accepts code via approved merge requests.

Given 2 developers working on the same feature, different pieces, what would be the best way to create a merge request for this feature:

1. each developer creates his own? (they both have each others code because in order to progress they've pushed and pulled from each other directly)

   - wouldn't this cause issues since the first creating the merge request would have the others changes? pushing one commit at a time would be really tedious. Maybe keeping a branch with only local changes and creating an integration branch? But then the merge request doesn't work on its own, nor makes much sense.
2. one of them creates a "complete" merge request for both?

   - reviewing it becomes a much bigger job since it's a lot more code and we can't have 2 owners of the merge request at once

Comment: Its good to have two different branches for two developers and after passing all tests let different merge request for different commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both developers part isn´t independently I would suggest you go for approach number 2, one developer creates a merge request containing both jobs. However, you can make this little less hard by:

-Make each developer to conduct code reviews on their part of the job in smaller pieces. While this would not avoid a code review on the entire work going to main branch, it will for sure makes rejection less like.

-For big features, whenever possible, each developer should generate smaller pieces of the job ("atomic commits") that are not dependent on the others job, this piece could then be merged into development branch and pulled from the other developer to continue his work. This way, when the feature is done it is already living in development branch and not on developer´s topic branch.

Per your description I believe your developers would have topic branches containing all work. You cannot separated both easily from topic branches standpoint. So go for approach number 2 and do sign by both developers.

Comment: Your option #2 is nice theoretically but in real world dev (different devs FE & BE) it's not really possible or easy at least. So yes my opt #2 seems the best. Wanted to see if someone else has a better idea! Thanks

Comment: Yes, if the feature cannot be divided in atomic commits than it shall be developed in a separated topic branch and than merged as one single bit commit. Nightmare to review, I lived this a lot in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Create a single feature branch (from master), that both programmers work on.  Both engineers should use ["atomic commits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_commit) so that the reviewer's job is straightforward.  If there are many other engineers merging to master during this feature's development, perform periodic [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) from master to ensure build integrity.

Comment: but how does this solve the isolated merge request problem? That's my original problem, not the way this is worked on. It's local, they can use feature branches is they want, for the merge request it really doesn't make any difference.

Comment: If the problem with the single (largish) merge request is the sheer size of the required review, and a single reviewer *must* review a single merge request, then the only other options I see are to create separate feature branches and merge requests by partitioning this story, or for the single reviewer to pair with another reviewer during the review.

Answer (score 1):

[Forked workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow) becomes really attractive in this situation (and works well with Github) which uses pull requests to send changes from the developer's personal fork back to the primary repository's repository.

- 'origin' remote points at developer's personal fork of the project on a server (usually stored in their personal area on Github, etc.).
- 'upstream' remote points at the official repository on some server.
- 'development' periodically gets merged into 'master' in the official repository (never the other way around)
- Both 'development' and 'master' in the official repository should always build / test cleanly.
- Developer creates a local branch, based off of development, to work a specific issue / subset of the story.
- When the code is ready for review and passes all tests, they rebase their local branch off of development one more time, then `git push` the branch to their private fork repository and create a pull request from their private fork/branch to the master repository/development branch.

Assuming the developer has a branch named 'i903-description-of-issue' (903 is a github issue number for us), and they need to rebase against development:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout development
git merge --ff-only upstream/development
git checkout i903-description-of-issue
git rebase development
git push origin i903-description-of-issue
```

So the developer is responsible for making sure their personal branch is always in-tune with the official 'development' branch on the main repository (via rebasing).  It uses pull requests to merge multiple-commits at a single go into the main 'development' branch.  This pull request model in Github (and other tools) allows for code review prior to accepting the PR.

If it's going to be a disruptive feature branch that will break the ability to continuously deploy 'development' branch to a QA server, then you probably need to break the new feature down into smaller bits that will be less disruptive.